# MySQL prepared statements with order by clause

Tags: mysql

I am using prepared statements in MySQL with 'order by' conditional clause. Using '?' and variables don't work with such things like ordering so I've decided to make it in other way. I set if conditions, but it's much more code. Maybe there is other option to reduce code and just changing 'order by' arguments?

```
IF sorting_column_index = 1 and sorting_column_mode = 0
        THEN PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT a.oid as \'oid\', 
        ...

        FROM table as a

        ...
        order by numero_annee desc LIMIT ?, ?';
        EXECUTE STMT USING @skip, @ROWS;
END IF;

IF sorting_column_index = 2 and sorting_column_mode = 1
        THEN PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT a.oid as \'oid\', 
        ...

        FROM table as a

        ...
        order by numero_ordre asc LIMIT ?, ?';
        EXECUTE STMT USING @skip, @ROWS;
END IF;
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, not using parameters for asc/desc but building your query string:

```
SET @sort_order = 'desc';
SET @my_limit = 5;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT whatever FROM whatever ORDER BY col1 ', @sort_order, ' LIMIT ?;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @my_limit;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: usefull and helps me save a lot of free space x)